# How to include an external jar file into the jar with package?

Tags: sbt

My project has dependency on an external jar. I have created a directory `lib` and have copied the jar file into it. This is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "approxstrmatch"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

unmanagedJars in Compile += file("lib/secondstring-20140729.jar")

libraryDependencies+="org.apache.spark"%%"spark-core"%"1.0.0"

resolvers += "AkkaRepository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

When I run `clean` and `package`, the external jar file does not get included in the generated jar file. Why?

This is the project layout:

```
project/build.sbt
lib/
src/.....
```

Answer (score 45):

Try this

```
libraryDependencies += "com.acme.common" % "commonclass" % "1.0" from "file:///Users/bwong/git/perf-tools/commonclass/target/scala-2.11/commonclass_2.11-1.0.jar"
```

I "sbt package" the common classproject and then just add that library dependency in my build.sbt in the dependent projects.

Thanks to http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2014/06/sbt-use-jar-file-for-librarydependencies.html for this hack.

Comment: How to do this in Dependencies.scala and replace the absolute path with the root directory lib folder path?

Comment: This is also mentioned in the documentation http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know how may I add only specified JAR file(s) to the target JAR file (not ALL dependent ones)?

Answer (score 38):

First of all, there is no need to specify `unmanagedJars` explicitly unless you have more complex configuration. Simply put your JAR files into the `lib` directory and they will be added to the classpath ([docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html)).

To package an executable JAR with all the necessary dependencies use one of the SBT plugins: [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) or [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/). `package` simply packages your classes into a jar and doesn't bother with including dependencies whatsoever.

The instructions in the docs of the plugins should be easy to guide you how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know how may I add only specified JAR file(s) to the target JAR file (not ALL dependent ones)?

Comment: @MaxU if you use sbt assembly you can exclude files as described here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#assemblyexcludedjars. Example: `assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := { 
  val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
  cp filter {_.data.getName == "compile-0.1.0.jar"}
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I believe this nice example should be part of your valuable answer ;)

Answer (score 21):

The trick is to figure out which `lib` directory to put your JAR in. You can do this by running the following in your sbt console: `show unmanagedBase`.

If you don't see your project there, you can run `show YOURPROJECT/unmanagedBase` to find the correct `lib` path.

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your build.sbt and clean & compile your project.

project/libs, where the project is the root directory of your project, put your jars in the libs folder.

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "libs"
```

Comment: latest command `unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "libs"`

Answer (score 2):

I was racking my brain with resolvers and settingKey vars, but it seems this is the most straight-forward way (https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html):

`resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"`

then just add to libraryDependencies as you normally would

`libraryDependencies += "<group>" % "<artifact>" % "<version>"`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Move `project/build.sbt` one level up where `lib` directory is and use [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin (as described in [the other answer by Aleksey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129521/1305344)).

If the project directory layout is as you use for your project, it's incorrect since `build.sbt` does not belong to the same build where `lib` does.

Since [sbt is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Full-Def.html#sbt+is+recursive) this `project/build.sbt` describes the project's build that governs the main one. Quoting [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Full-Def.html#sbt+is+recursive):

> The project directory is another project inside your project which
>   knows how to build your project. The project inside project can (in
>   theory) do anything any other project can do. Your build definition is
>   an sbt project.
>
> And the turtles go all the way down. If you like, you can tweak the
>   build definition of the build definition project, by creating a
>   project/project/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

one of the solutions is, when you build that jar in sbt, do `sbt publish-local`

Comment: this is my preferred approach too, easier than copying files around; reference here:  http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Publishing.html