# Extracting External JAR's Version & Adding to SBT

Tags: jar, sbt

Given a JAR, namely `ojdbc6.jar` from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html), I tried to add it as an external JAR to my SBT project.

Note -I'm using this project as a sandbox, which explains the external JAR approach.

First, I copied it to my `$SBT_HOME/lib` directory, per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25129521/409976) to use unmanaged JARs.

To determine the version of the JAR, i.e. the third argument of the `libraryDependency`, I ran:

```
$unzip ojdbc6.jar 
$cat ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF 
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.5
Created-By: 1.5.0_51-b10 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Vendor: Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Title: JDBC
Implementation-Version: 11.2.0.4.0
```

So, then I updated my `build.sbt` with:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.oracle.jdbc"   % "ojdbc6" % "11.2.0.4.0"
)
```

But, upon running `sbt run`, I see:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.oracle.jdbc#ojdbc6;11.2.0.4.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

How can I add this JAR to my SBT project as an external dependency?