# How to add unmanaged Dependencies in Scala?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I am a newbie to *Scala* and I wanted to add an external JAR file into the program and use it's functions.

So what I did was copied the JAR into `lib` folder and then added the below line as well in my *SBT* file:

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib"
```

I followed this post [Link For Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129227/how-to-include-an-external-jar-file-into-the-jar-with-package)

After this, when I import the class I find a class not found error. I am not sure why it is throwing a class not found when I added the jar into the `lib` folder.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your sbt version?

Comment: Usually, it is sufficient to put your unmanaged JAR files into the `lib` directory of your project - that is the default definition of `unmanagedBase` and so you do not need to redefine it in your _SBT_ build file. (The only time you need to do that is if you wanted to put unmanaged JARs in a folder with a different name to `lib`.) What is the name of the unmanaged JAR file, what is the exact `ClassNotFoundException` message? What does your `import` statement look like?